# Links on images are not working on mobile

Tags: php, html, css

When i open my page on Samsung phone, links on images are not working but when i try that on my pc everything working properly.

Also, if i remove `id="profileimage"` on img part, links are working. Could you help me?

```
  <style>
  ol {padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: none;}
  #leftpanel{margin-top: 5%;}
  #enjoy{text-align: center;}
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {img {width: 30%; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 2px;}}
  @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {img {width: 19%; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 2px;}}
  </style> 

      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    });
    </script>
</head>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
    <ol class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="middle">
        <li>
        <?php while ($r1 = $q->fetch()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $r1['id'];?>"> <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo $r1['pic'];?>"></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </li>
        <li>
        <?php while ($r2 = $q2->fetch()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $r2['id'];?>"> <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo $r2['pic'];?>"></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </li>
        <li>
        <?php while ($r3 = $q3->fetch()): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $r3['id'];?>"> <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo $r3['pic'];?>"></a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: May or may not be related, but ids on HTML elements should be unique.  You are using `id="profileimage"` multiple times.  If you are binding handlers by id, this is likely going to be an issue.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the CSS in the media query.

Comment: When I had this issue it was due to the image not thinking it was being clicked. Does the link highlight? Any idea if it is really being picked?

Comment: You should consider removing id="profileimage" and adding it as a class if possible (class="img-round profileimage") as IDs should be a unique identifier. Additionally, is it possible that you have a javascript/jquery on click handler set for the '#profile-image' that prevents the default behavior of the link?

Comment: @TimothyBomer i remove id="profileimage" and make that to 'img {width: 30%; height: auto; margin: 0; padding: 2px;}'

Comment: @TimothyBomer and i also publish my all codes on that page

Answer (score 1):

```
<ol class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12" align="middle">
```

When i remove `class="hidden-lg hidden-md col-sm-12 col-xs-12"` part, it fix. Thank you for your help

Comment: Good find. It looks like bootstrap was hiding it behind other elements on the page. Another option would be to adjust the z-index to bring the div forward in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing your code, I believe I have found the issue and a solution. It looks like your images are being blocked by other elements on the page. Add `style="position:relative; z-index: 10;"` to your div containing the mobile images to bring your div to the front of the viewport and this should allow them to be clickable.